# In haskell how can I make binary digits from a decimal number?

Tags: haskell, binary, decimal

Implement the Bin function, which returns the binary digits of a non-negative integer in reverse order!

Example:

- Bin 0 == []
- Bin 1 == [1]
- Bin 2 == [0,1]
- Bin 10 == [0, 1, 0, 1]

```
Bin :: Integer -> [Int]
Bin 0 = []
Bin a `div` 2 = b
Bin a `mod` 2 = c
```

I would like to give back my divide result to the Bin function and mod it again and etc..
How can I solve this ? Can I get some help ?

Comment: functions are written in lowercase, so `bin` instead of `Bin`.

Comment: What did you expect ```Bin a `div` 2 = b``` to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one parameter, so the implementation of `bin` looks like:

```
bin :: Integer -> [Int]
bin 0 = []
bin n = …
```

we can determine the modulo and divide the number by two with [**`divMod :: Integral a => a -> a -> (a, a)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:divMod), we can use a `where` clause to set variables `d` and `m`:

```
bin :: Integer -> [Int]
bin 0 = []
bin n = …
    where (d, m) = divMod n 2
```

we can not use `m` directly, since this is an `Integer`, and not an `Int`, we can work with [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to convert the `Integer` to an `Int`.

We thus will need to construct a list with `m` as an element of that list, and use recursion to determine the other items of the list. The `…` part should thus construct such list. I leave that as an exercise. Hint: you can construct a list with `x` as first item and `xs` as a list of remaining items with `(x:xs)`.

Comment: Like this : Bin n = (x:m:xs) = x : Bin m xs ? I added m to a list and I would like to give back the m and the remaining list. Is this correct or I have to do something with it ?

Comment: @hello16: what is `(x:m:xs)` doing here?

Comment: They are just the items of the list.

Comment: @hello16: and then what is `(x : bin m xs)`? An definition can only contain *one* `=` per clause.

Comment: Oh, so I can use only one =. Than bin n =  bin m xs . I would like to give back the m and the rest of the list with this. Do I need to give back m or I just have to give back xs?

Comment: @hello16: you should construct a list, where you use `d` and `m` (and `fromIntegral` and `bin`). You thus need to construct an expression `(... : ...)` where the first `...` determines the first item of the list, and the second `...` is a list of remaining elements. The two `...`s are thus expressions.

Comment: Is this the right side of the equality ?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem